# Why dereferenced Pointer is being passed to pointer type?

Tags: go, pointers

```
type animal struct{
  sound string
}

func (a *animal) bark(s string) {
  (*a).sound = s
}

var yourAnimal *animal 
//yourAnimal is an address so this makes sense i.e. the receiver expects an address since it is of type *animal:
yourAnimal.bark("woof")
fmt.Println(*yourAnimal)

//But why does this prints out the value "waff"?
(*yourAnimal).bark("waff")
fmt.Println(*yourAnimal)  // 2
```

Why does this (the last Println where I have //2) prints out the value "waff"? What does it even mean (*animal)? This is dereferencing animal so is a value and that value is passed to the receiver which is accepting a pointer to animal not a value? Why is this legal? The correct one should be an address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The receiver `bark` has a pointer receiver. That means, the call `(*yourAnimal).bark("waff")` is actually `(&(*yourAnimal)).bark("waff")`, which is the same object as the previous call.

Comment: This feature is covered at the end of the [Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) section in the language specification.